# nodejs unit test undefined after required controller

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

I am try to make a unit test for a controller in a project that use nodeJS, but when I call a function of a controller the test return that this controller is undefined.

This is my MK.js code:

```js
MK = {}

MK.deleteAgent() {

}

module.exports = MK
```

My test code MK.spec.js:

```js
const assert = require("assert");
const sinon = require("sinon");

const { MK } = require("./MK");

describe("MK controllers", function () {
    let rt_model;
    beforeEach(function () {
        rt_model = {
            findAll: sinon.fake.resolves()
        }
    });

    describe("deleteAgent", function () {
        it("should call rt_model.findAll", function (done) {
            // a mock for the Web response
            const response = {
                status: () => null,
                json: () => {
                    assert.strictEqual(rt_model.findAll.callCount, 1);
                    done();
                }
            };

            MK.deleteAgent(null, response);
        });
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Restore the default sandbox here
        sinon.restore();
    });
});
```

But ther result that I get when run test is that MK is undefined

Comment: Try `const MK = require("./MK");` isntead of `const { MK } = require("./MK");`

Comment: Ready. That' s was the problem that I amd exporting only MK and not { MK }. Thank